# Can't use specific Locales in Numberformat

Tags: java, locale, number-formatting, numberformatter

I just want to use ***danish*** as the locale when getting a currency numberformat (*where it says French now*) but no locale "code" can be used for it.

```
NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.FRENCH).format(pay);
```

When I check out the `getAvailableLocales()` method I get several that mention `DK`: `da_DK_#Latn`, `da_DK`, `en_DK`, `fo_DK` but the locale code just appears red in the code and the IDE says `"Rename reference"`.

Only "big" languages show up such as french and can be used.

I don't know how to use a locale that isn't one of the big languages that automatically pop up as suggestions when you write the function.

Answer (score 4):

> Only "big" languages show up such as french and can be used

There is no constant in the `Locale` class for the locale that you are looking for, but you can instantiate it using one of the constructors defined by this class.

To get the proper formatting for the currency, need a [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) that expects two string arguments: language and country codes.

```
Locale locale = new Locale("da", "DK");
NumberFormat currencyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
System.out.println(currencyFormat.format(1000));
```

**Output**

```
1.000,00 kr.
```